# Invalid token '=' in class member declaration in C#

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public class Probna1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Person person = new Person();
    person.FirstName = "Joseph";
    person.LastName = "Samuel";
    FirstNameTextBox.DataContext = person;
}
```

The signs = have this error mesage: Invalid token '=' in class member declaration.

I have Class Person with public fields FirstName and LastName with {get; set;}

Comment: you should initialize your field in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set your properties directly in the class, you have to put your declarations in a method.

Try to do it in the constructor like this:

```
public class Probna1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Person person;

    public Probna1()
    {
        person = new Person();
        person.FirstName = "Joseph";
        person.LastName = "Samuel";
        FirstNameTextBox.DataContext = person;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpfull, but now I have error message: The name 'FirstNameTextBox' does not exist in the current context. That is TextBox from one View page.

Answer (score 2):

Milos, I get the impression that you are new not only to C#, but also to object-oriented programming. FirstNameTextBox belongs to your Windows Form, so you would have to reference that form from your class. However, that's not usually a good idea. What are you trying to accomplish?

I would recommend a good introductory book on C#, so you can understand the basics. I like the "Step by Step" book series, available on Amazon or Barnes and Noble. Happy programming!

Comment: I'm not new to programming, but I'm new to connecting view page with model.

Comment: I resolved problem making the WPF application, not ASP.NET MVC application.